# MFMailComposeViewController image attachment and HTML body

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Hopefully simple question:

Is there a way to attach an image to the `MFmailcomposeviewcontroller` AND have an HTML formatted body? Everytime I try, I can do one or the other, but not both. If I set `isHTML:YES`, it gives me the HTML body format, but then it embeds my image attachment (not what I want). If I do `isHTML:NO`, the image is attached as a file (what I want) but the body message obviously won't respect my br line breaks.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd say you answered your own question. MFMailComposeViewController is pretty limited.

Comment: I did it once I believe, but I'm not sure anymore. I guess you add your image with `[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/jpg(or png whatever)" fileName:@"image.whatever"];` right? Try to set the mimeType to nil, maybe this will work. No promises though, I did this a long time ago and can't test right now

Comment: I'll say. I did just figure out that I can use \n for line breaks with plain text instead of br's and then set isHTML:NO and have the attachment the way I need it. Just unfortunate that I can't have some bolded text and other nice formatting features too.

Comment: Did you try my proposal?

Comment: Just did, but the image attachment came through as an unformatted .dat file, which doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't the image have a file extension? Sorry, I'm just curious. If it doesn't work, sorry that I bothered you :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't touch on the image setup. It's an image the user takes with the UIImagePicker. So it's just a UIImage I place in an array until sent. It doesn't get saved anywhere, so I guess it wouldn't technically have an extension(?).

Comment: Yes but you do specify a filename, don't you? So, if it's a PNG specify the filename as <imagename>.png, otherwise if it's a jpg, <imagename>.jpg and see what happens

Comment: Oh, I see what you were saying. I tried again and it still embedded the image in the email with the isHTML:YES and a nil mimeType.

Answer (score 1):

-(IBAction)clickSend:(id)sender{

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
NSString *bodyString=[self MessageBody];

[mailComposer setMessageBody:bodyString isHTML:YES];

[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

-(NSMutableString *)MessageBody{

```
NSMutableString *bodyString=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"<html><body>"];
[bodyString appendString:@"<p>Sending Email with Image</p>"];




     [bodyString appendString:@"<div style=\"background:url(http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQVd7uDWzEt7J4jimllpd9oTNBsQn-GFWUYIeGoiK_4-o4tPYGz); height:280px; width:510px; margin:60px 5px;\">"];



[bodyString appendString:@"</div> </body> </html>"];

return bodyString;
```

}

Hope, this will help you